# 1912 Steinway B

Tags: piano, tuning, strings, repair

I purchased a rebuilt 1912 Steinway B four months ago. It has been tuned three times since I got it. Each time, it seems like after playing 20-30 minutes the intervals start to migrate. Perhaps it is overtones or beats but it’s enough to be distracting to me. Two technicians have said the soundboard and bridges were well done. I think the action has older parts but for the life of me I cannot figure out why this piano doesn’t stay in tune better or have a better tone. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you could arrange with a technician to tune it, then stay for 30 minutes while you (or the technician) plays.

Comment: Do you know if the piano has been restrung shortly before? If so the string might need a few tunings to settle.

Comment: This is one of the times location would be helpful - both of OP *and* the piano itself: in the sun, by a heater, in an unheated room, etc?

Comment: How long ago was the piano rebuilt?

Comment: Can we get you to auctually ask a question in the title of this question?

Comment: We typically don't have discussion on this website. This is not a forum. Can we ask you to ask an actual question which can be answered in an definitive manner?

Comment: Hi Neil, my apologies for not posing a question in the heading. I’m new to this page. The seller (a very large and well-known entity) told me the piano was rebuilt by someone else within the past 10-20 years. However, the parts have been indentified as being from the 1980s. The strings are not new. The pin block and soundboard are new. Does this clarify the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Older pianos will eventually develop problems with keeping their tuning, because the holes the tuning pins are in get worn. This needs to be dealt with using thicker tuning pins and/or bushing out the holes.

Comment: The piano is recently rebuilt.

Comment: @phoog - yes, I got that. That doesn't exclude the possibility that it was rebuilt incompetently.  But I agree, new strings stretching out is (hopefully) the more likely cause.

Answer (score 1):

After only 4 months and 3 tunings, it'd be back to the shop - I guess that's where it came from. Rebuilds should mean good as new (almost). So there ought to be some sort of guarantee for more than 4 months, but be quick!

Lazy's suggestion about new strings could be a good reason.

Comment: Good answer, I'll just add that in my experience the tuner puts the piano through its paces at the end of the appointment, just as a matter of course.  Also a good tuner will check location and humidity.  And when the first tuning failed they should have sent their most experienced person to see what's going on.

Comment: The strings are not new…..they are from when the piano was restrung after a new board was put in….probably 20+ years ago. The piano is in my apartment in New York City, away from the windows and radiator. In fact, I turned the radiator off.